# How can I write (and fix) this code without loops in java

Tags: java, loops, if-statement, switch-statement

just wondering how can i switch this code to a different one without any loops but still keep what its doing. only use if\switch
and fix it actually it dosent seems to work

```
  public static int countWords(String s){

    int wordCount = 0;

    boolean word = false;
    int endOfLine = s.length() - 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        // if the char is a letter, word = true.
        if (Character.isLetter(s.charAt(i)) && i != endOfLine) {
            word = true;
            // if char isn't a letter and there have been letters before,
            // counter goes up.
        } else if (!Character.isLetter(s.charAt(i)) && word) {
            wordCount++;
            word = false;
            // last word of String; if it doesn't end with a non letter, it
            // wouldn't count without this.
        } else if (Character.isLetter(s.charAt(i)) && i == endOfLine) {
            wordCount++;
        }
    }
    return wordCount;
}
```

Comment: *without any loops but still keep what its doing. only use if\switch* That is **not** possible. But you could do `return s.split("\\s+").length;`

Comment: Try `s.split("\\PL+")` which splits the string `s` on any non-character.

Comment: "it actually it dosent seems to work"—Then post a [mre] and tell us how it doesn't work

Comment: @A.B Can you explain a bit what you want to achieve? For example, I ran your code with the string "aaddrr12345;2C" and as result I got 2. Why? What are you trying to count?

Comment: @A.B for example, in the string I tried "aaddrr12345;2C" i count 7 non-letter in the middle of the string, plus a letter at the end, so the expected result is 8, why do you expect 2 instead?

Comment: @A.B I had initially misunderstood the intention of your algorithm, then I had a thought about it and I added in "answer" my proposal solution. Hope that answer your question, if so please accept and upvote. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about your original question, but it seems like your problem can be solved by replacing your function with

```
return s.split(" ").length
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood well, I can sum-up your algorithm with the following two cases:

1. Count all "non-words character" which are preceded by "word character"
2. Increments the counter if the string ends with a Letter.

That can be definitely implemented without loop, by using the `String.split()` function with a proper pattern.

There can be many solution, but just to give you an idea, here is an example of implementation, where I split the string with "all alphabetic character" pattern (`\\p{Alpha}+`) .
In case the string starts with a non-word (first element of the String array), the counter is decremented.
In addition, the counter is incremented if case n.2 is verified.
You can see the difference between your implementation (method `countWords`) and mine (method `countWordsNoLoop`):

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class WordCounter {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String test1 = "aaddrr12345;2C";
        String test2 = "1111aaddrr12345;2C";
        String test3 = "aaaaa7877sssss1111aaddrr12345;2C";
        
        
        System.out.println("Counter " + test1 + " with loop: " + countWords(test1));
        System.out.println("Counter " + test1 + " without loop: " + countWordsNoLoop(test1));
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Counter " + test2 + " with loop: " + countWords(test2));
        System.out.println("Counter " + test2 + " without loop: " + countWordsNoLoop(test2));
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Counter " + test3 + " with loop: " + countWords(test3));
        System.out.println("Counter " + test3 + " without loop: " + countWordsNoLoop(test3));
    }
    
    public static int countWordsNoLoop(String s){
        String[] splitString =  s.split("\\p{Alpha}+");
        
        int wordCount = (s.startsWith(splitString[0]) ? splitString.length - 1 : splitString.length) + 
                        (Character.isLetter(s.charAt(s.length()-1)) ? 1 : 0 );

        return wordCount;
    }
    
    
    
    public static int countWords(String s){

        int wordCount = 0;
    
        boolean word = false;
        int endOfLine = s.length() - 1;
    
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            // if the char is a letter, word = true.
            if (Character.isLetter(s.charAt(i)) && i != endOfLine) {
                word = true;
                // if char isn't a letter and there have been letters before,
                // counter goes up.
            } else if (!Character.isLetter(s.charAt(i)) && word) {
                wordCount++;
                word = false;
                // last word of String; if it doesn't end with a non letter, it
                // wouldn't count without this.
            } else if (Character.isLetter(s.charAt(i)) && i == endOfLine) {
                wordCount++;
            }
        }
        return wordCount;
    }
}
```

And here is the output:

```
Counter aaddrr12345;2C with loop: 2
Counter aaddrr12345;2C without loop: 2

Counter 1111aaddrr12345;2C with loop: 2
Counter 1111aaddrr12345;2C without loop: 2

Counter aaaaa7877sssss1111aaddrr12345;2C with loop: 4
Counter aaaaa7877sssss1111aaddrr12345;2C without loop: 4
```